# useEffect not being triggered at all on component load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a useEffect that I want to run just once on component load, except in this case it isn't running at all and I am not sure why. Here is the code:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect} from "react"
import { UserContext } from "../users/UserProvider"



export const ProfileInfo = (props) =>{
const {cbUser, getSingleCbUser} = useContext(UserContext)


useEffect(()=> {
    getSingleCbUser(props.match.params.id)
    
},[])






    return(
        <>
            <section className="info__container">
                <div className="left__info">
                    <p>{cbUser.user.username}</p>
                    <p>{cbUser.user.first_name}</p>
                    <p>{cbUser.user.last_name}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>{cbUser.user.date_joined}</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
    )
}
```

It seems that the useEffect is not being triggered at all. When I replace whats inside with `console.log("test")` I see no console log in the browser console. It seems that the useEffect is just being passed over. I am using a useEffect the same way in another component and it is working fine. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `useEffect` fires when not page loaded but component rendered.

Comment: In the dependency array "[ ]" of the useEffect, can you palce `getSingleCbUser `?
From `[ ]` to `[getSingleCbUser]`

Comment: @Magofoco I tried that and still seems to be skipping over the useEffect for some reason. I put a breakpoint on the useEffect line in the debugger and its hitting that first line `useEffect(()=> {` but then just skips down to the return statement

Comment: can you paste your code on codesandbox ? so that i can see a live demo and fixing the bug would get easy